# Suppose $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $H=(\mathbb{Z}_m,+)$. Show that $nH=H$ if and only if $m$ and $n$ are coprime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $m \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $H=(\mathbb{Z}_m,+)$. Show that $nH=H$ if and only if $m$ and $n$ are coprime. I have no idea what is $H^n$. Can anyone guide me ?

Remarks; Guys, sorry for the confusion. I have edited the question.

Comment: Probably $H^n = \{n*h| h \in H \}$, as Boris pointed out.

Comment: First take a generator $g$ of $H$, and show that $g^n$ generates $H$ if $m$ and $n$ are coprime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean $n H$, the set of multiples, not $H^{n}$, the set of pwoers.

Otherwise, take $m = 4$ and $n = 5$, you get
$$
\{0^5, 1^5, 2^5, 3^5 \} = \{ 0, 1, 3 \},
$$
where I am using integers to denote elements of $\Bbb{Z}_{m}$.

Then this depend on a result that tells you that if the element $a$ of the (additive) group $G$ has order $m$, then its multiple $n a$ has order
$$
\frac{m}{\gcd(m,n)}.
$$

Comment: can you elaborate further ? I don understand your hint.

Comment: With pleasure, but @MathGems has a better solution. Anyway, if $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, then $n \cdot \bar 1$ (I'm writing $\bar a$ for the elements of $\Bbb{Z}_m$) will have period $m$, and thus generate the whole of $\Bbb{Z}_m$. If $\gcd(m,n) > 1$, then $n \cdot \bar a$ will have order less than $m$ for all $\bar a \in \Bbb{Z}_m$, and so the map won't be surjective.

Comment: So the map defined by @MathGems is $f:\mathbb{Z}_m \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m$?

Comment: Yes, it's the map $\bar a \mapsto n \bar a = \overline{na}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ On $\rm\,\Bbb Z_m,\,\ x\to nx\:$ is $1$-$1\!\!\iff\!\!$ onto $\!\!\iff\!$ $\rm jn\equiv 1\!\!\iff\!\! jn\!+\!km=1\!\!\iff\!\! gcd(n,m)=1$

Comment: may I know what is the codomain of your map?

Comment: It's a map *on* $\rm\,S = \Bbb Z_m,\,$ so the domain $\rm= S = $ codomain. Note that, in an additive group $\rm\, n x = x+\cdots+x\:$ denotes a sum of $\rm\,n\,$ terms, the $\rm\,n$'th *multiple* of $\rm\,x\:$ (it is the additive analog of the multplicative notion of an $\rm\,n$'th *power* $\rm\,x^n).$

Comment: If I want to prove the map is one to one, can you help me in my working? Suppose $nx_1=nx_2$ iff $n(x_1 -x_2)=mt$ for some integer $t$. Then I stuck here.

Comment: How we conclude that $n\mathbb{Z}_m=\mathbb{Z}_m$?

Comment: Chase the above arrows from right to left. Alternatively, directly, use Euclid's lemma, that $\rm\,gcd(m,n)=1,\ m\mid nx\:\Rightarrow\:m\mid x.$

Comment: So if the map is bijective, then the two groups are the same?

Comment: Yes, because a map on a finite set is $1$-$1$ iff onto.

Comment: What I mean is if we have a map $f:A \rightarrow A$ such that $a \rightarrow na$ and $f$ is bijective, then the two sets are equal ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that one must write $nH=H$ instead of $H^n=H$ (addition instead of multiplication).

Comment: Oh, yes of course you are right, $H$ is $\mathbb Z_m$ with $+$.